CANoe 18 SP2: START MEASUREMENT ABORTED
I working with a DEMOversion , I had this issues when I launch CANOE projects , the start of measurement aborted each time a click on simualation.
This the message that I get :
=>"nodelayer-dll 'canoeilnlvector.vmodule' could not be loaded%0d%0
[enter image description here][1]
